# Cannot scale crosswalk webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, crosswalk

I use Crosswalk library instead of android standart webview. 
When try to scale crosswalk webview like this.

```
 webView.setPivotX(0);
 webView.setPivotY(0);
 webView.setX(original_x * 1.2);
 webView.setY(original_y * 1.2);
 webView.setScaleX(1.2);
 webView.setScaleY(1.2);
```

but crosswalk webview size didn't change. It's look like first loaded sizes. Also i can scale android standart webview successfully with this code.

[image: First loaded]

[image: after scale]

sorry for my english

thank for your help

Comment: I resolved problem. 
When set "XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.ANIMATABLE_XWALK_VIEW, true);" wiew scaled successfully.

Comment: Also you can check [this page](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-5969)